An argument using Chebotarev density theorem
I was having trouble with the following argument. I think I got it but still wanted to post in case I missed something. Here $\rho_{E_d,N}:\text{Gal}_\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$ is a Galois representation for the $N$-torsion of an elliptic curve (more precisely a quadratic twist $E_d$ of the curve $E$).

If I understand correctly, the Chebotarev density theorem implies that the images of Frobenius elements are dense over the image $\rho_{E_d,N}(\text{Gal}_\mathbb{Q})$. Therefore, any element $g\in\rho_{E_d,N}(\text{Gal}_\mathbb{Q})$ can be approximated by Frobenius. On the other hand, if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime above $p$ we have
$$ Tr(\rho_{E_d,N}(\text{Frob}_\mathfrak{p})) = a_p(E_d). $$
The $d$ is chosen so that $a_p(E_d) \not\equiv -2$ mod $N$ for all primes $p$ of good reduction (that is, all but finitely many primes) with $p\equiv 1$ mod $N$, hence if $Tr(g)\equiv -2$ mod $N$ then $g$ cannot be approximated by Frobenius elements over this set of primes. Remembering $\det(\rho(\text{Frob}_\mathfrak{p})) \equiv p$ mod $N$, we get the following:
If $g\in\rho_{E_d,N}(\text{Gal}_\mathbb{Q})$ has trace $-2$ mod $N$, then it cannot be approximated by the images of Frobenius elements with determinant $1$.
In particular, if $\det(g)=1$ then $g$ cannot be approximated by the images of Frobenius elements at all. Thus there are no elements $g\in\rho_{E_d,N}(\text{Gal}_\mathbb{Q})$ with $Tr(g)=-2$ and $\det(g)=1$.
One question comes to mind: what do we mean by approximating here exactly? We approximate matrices with the N-adic norm (assuming $N$ prime)? Isnt it possible to still approximate a matrix even if you get a different trace mod $N$?

$\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z)$ is a finite group, so the topology on it is the discrete topology!

So Chebotarev here implies that every element in the image comes from a Frobenius element?

Exactly. One way to think about it is that the representation factors through $G = \mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q)$ for some finite extension $K$ over $\mathbb Q$. The set of elements $g\in G$ with $\mathrm{Tr}(g) \equiv -2\pmod N$ is either empty or is a conjugacy class $C$ in $G$. In the latter case, Chebotarev tells you that density of Frobenious elements in $C$ is $|C|/|G|$.
